# Python error when implementing class

Tags: python, class

```
class DetailedScore(Score):
'''A subclass of Score adding level'''

    def __init__(self, points, initials, level):
        '''
        (Score, int, str, int) -> NoneType

        Create a score including number of points, initials, and level.
        '''

        super().__init__(points, initials)
        self.level = level

    def __str__(self):
        '''
        Return a string representation of DetailedScore formated:

        'The student with initials 'KTH' scored 100 points, the student is in level 10'
        '''

        score_str = super().__str__()

        return '{}, the student is in level {}'.format(score_str, self.level)

    def __repr__(self):
        '''
        Return a string representation of DetailedScore formated:

        'DetailedScore(100, 'KTH', 10)'
        '''

        return 'DetailedScore({}, {}, {})'.format(self.points, self.initials, self.level)

score5 = DetailedScore(1000, 'JQP', 100)
score6 = DetailedScore(999, 'ABC', 99)
score7 = DetailedScore(999, 'BBB', 15)
score8 = DetailedScore(1, 'KTH', 12)
```

I am trying to finish this class, and am not sure why I keep getting an error when trying to build.

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/KoryHershock/Documents/Python/[Kory_Hershock]_final.py", line 187, in <module>
    score5 = DetailedScore(1000, 'JQP', 100)
  File "/Users/KoryHershock/Documents/Python/[Kory_Hershock]_final.py", line 162, in __init__
    super().__init__(points, initials)
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Python 2, you must write `super(DetailedScore, self)`, not `super()`.

It is Python 3 that also allows the no-argument form with the compiler inserting the appropriate class object taken from lexical context.

Comment: I have python 3 installed on my computer, how would I make Sublime Text 2 run it? Or how would I run python 3 through terminal?

Comment: @KoryHershock The Python 3 executable is typically called `python3`. How to set it up in Sublime is probably best asked in a Sublime-related forum.

Answer (score 2):

Change `super().__whatever__()` to `super(Score, self).__whatever__()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, trying to run python3 which is installed on my computer, how would I make Sublime Text 2 run it? Or how would I run the program in terminal with python3?